# Errors when trying to start a VirtualEnv OS X

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv

I am new to virtual environments and trying to start one to run django, and I have tried several ways and keep getting errors.  I think that it may have do with different versions of python, but I am a bit lost.  Does anybody know how to fix this issue with it not linking to correct sys.prefix, and why would it say the virtualenv is not compatible, I believe I installed i right and it says there's a new python executable.  Thank you for any help.

```
Christophers-MacBook-Pro:~ cccmusicality$ virtualenv env
Using base prefix '/Applications/anaconda'
New python executable in /Users/cccmusicality/env/bin/python
ERROR: The executable /Users/cccmusicality/env/bin/python is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is '/Users/cccmusicality' (should be '/Users/cccmusicality/env')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

Comment: What versions of Python are installed on your system?

Comment: Willem, I am running Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda 4.2.0 (x86_64)